# Trouble in linking code to an object file of an assembly language

Tags: java, assembly, linker, virtual-machine, loader

I was able to successfully make an object file of a sic assembly program

The command i did for that was

```
 java -cp sictools-java.jar sic.Asm a.asm
```

**But i am having trouble in linking it
**To run linker****

```
java -cp out/make/sictools.jar sic.Link -o out.obj in1.obj in2.obj ...
```

I was trying with this set of codes

I cant figure out what is sic.Link

https://github.com/jurem/SicTools

To be frank i am very very new to assembly set of coding

I am fiddle with sets of tools to get familar and to have some hands on experience with low level programming

[image]

Can you please guide me on how to set these up and make it running and find what all vallues are there in  each registers of this virtual machine

I would be very thankful for a guidence on how to make this system work and figure out what all values are left in the registers after the porgram execition in the graphics mode .. which according to documentaion can be obtained from

```
java -cp out/make/sictools.jar sic.Link -g
```